# Соблюдена ли лексическая сочетаемость

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Уместно ли употреблено причастие "уплотнённых" в данном контексте -  в значении сжавшихся?

В руке — лишь горстка уже таких почти уплотнённых минут, прежде чем полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием — и потеряю голову.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, так:

*В руке — лишь горстка **предельно уплотнённых** минут, прежде чем полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием,  **а потом** — потеряю голову.*

**Смысл такой**: до полночи осталось мало времени (и оно предельно уплотнено), а потом я потеряю голову (= утрачу контроль).

Можно еще **запятую** поставить:

*В руке — лишь горстка предельно уплотнённых минут, прежде чем полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием, — **и потеряю** голову.*

Но все равно на вставку **похоже.**

Comment: А почему нельзя оставить конец предложения, как у меня: "— и потеряю голову"?

Comment: Мне кажется, что смысл будет непонятен. Я вижу здесь сложное предложение, а с двумя тире  структура неясно прочитывается.  Похоже на вставку, обособленную двумя тире. Какая-то доработка концовки нужна.

Comment: Спасибо Вам! Это главная часть предложения (без учёта распространений внутри)

Comment: А уместно ли употреблено причастие "уплотнённых" в данном контексте - в значении сжавшихся?

Comment: Слово "уплотненный" прочитывается как обобщение, поэтому в него можно вложить любую конкретику, нужную вам.

Comment: Я на протяжении трёх недель пытался это понять! Спасибо, Вам!!

Comment: А если остановиться на таком варианте моего предложения:
 
В руке — лишь горстка (почти) предельно уплотнённых минут, прежде чем полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием, — и потеряю голову.

Иначе получается, что горстка минут уже предельно уплотнена (то есть нет времени вовсе) хотя подразумевается, что осталась горстка (то есть ещё некоторое количество времени) до его предельного уплотнения (то есть до того самого момента, когда их не останется и настанет полночь)
Или я в чём-то ошибся? 

Поправьте меня, пожалуйста, если это так

Comment: И я не совсем понял, что Вы имеете ввиду под вставкой, уточните пожалуйста. Первый раз встречаюсь с таким понятием и соответственно таким объяснением

Comment: Извините, пожалуйста, мне сложно дат вам ответ, так как надо подумать. Я попробую сделать это позже. А вставка – это особая конструкция в синтаксисе, как бы второй план речи.  Вставка не входит в основной состав предложения и обычно обособляется двумя тире.Можно кратко посмотреть здесь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

Comment: Понимаю, ничего страшного) сам несколько растерялся, слишком много неочевидных смысловых нюансов, а ответа буду ждать столько сколько нужно. А вставку я применим только потому, что всегда раздражало непомерное количество местоимения "я" в произведениях от первого лица. Ведь и так понятно, что идёт повествование от первого лица, если автором не указано иное

Comment: Посмотрел правило, Спасибо, Вам! Не думал, что это может восприниматься, как уточнение, ведь оно всегда заключается в скобки, надо же - удивительно

Comment: Мы стараемся избегать повтора тире, чтобы не создавалось впечатление парного знака. Поэтому я предложила доработать грамматику, чтобы второе тире не контактировало с первым. По поводу "я" вы абсолютно правы, неоправданный повтор местоимений - это стилистическая погрешность.

Comment: Уплотнять можно только жильцов, пассажиров на заднем сиденье - людей, но не минуты. У этого глагола сильный и живучий советский культурно-исторический подтекст, поэтому сжавшиеся минуты - гораздо лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравится слово уплотнённых, но предложение надо допиливать и общая недосказанность неясна:

В руке — лишь горстка уже таких, почти уплотнённых, минут; один вздох, полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием и потеряю голову...

Comment: А уместно ли употреблено причастие "уплотнённых" в данном контексте - в значении сжавшихся?

Comment: в значении сжавших наверное нет, но сжавших, давящих было бы банально, а мне нравится именно уплотнённых.

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ**

Я отчасти меняю **грамматику** предложения по сравнению с первым ответом. Вообще говоря, вопрос непростой. Нужно проверить значение слова "уплотненный", подобрать грамматическую структуру предложения и убедиться в том, что смысл предложения **правильно понят**.

1. **Словарь**

**УПЛОТНИТЬ**, св. что. 4. Заполнить какое-л. время большим **количеством дел**, занятий. У. рабочее время. У. сутки. // Сделать **более коротким, сократить, сжать.**

2. Два временных значения  для глагола "уплотнить" в сочетании "уплотненные минуты":

**Сжавшиеся минуты:**  их просто мало, очень мало.

**Сжавшиеся минуты:** их определенное / известное количество, но за это время надо  успеть очень многое.

3. Нас, вероятно,  интересует значение **очень короткого** времени. Смысл такой:

(1) *Так мало времени осталось,  **прежде чем** (2) наступит полночь и (3) я потеряю голову.*

Это СПП с однородными **придаточными времени**, связанными союзом И. В нем 3 предикативные основы:

*(1) В руке — лишь горстка уже таких предельно уплотнённых минут, //  **прежде чем** (2) полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием и (3) я потеряю голову.*

Такая трактовка **верна?**

4. Синтаксис предложения и так **сложен** для восприятия, поэтому нельзя его бесконечно усложнять, иначе понять предложение будет затруднительно. Соответственно, **второе** тире нужно убрать и лучше оставить **местоимение «я».**

Нужно в чем-то надо пойти  на уступку, чтобы  структура предложения  корректно **прочитывалась.**

**Примечание**

Синтаксис предложения представляется мне **очень интересным,** как и его  **лексическое** наполнение. Даже сложность вызывает положительные **эмоции,** потому что слишком простая грамматика  выглядит **скучно и заурядно**. А этот вопрос также очень важен во всех отношениях, в том числе для успешного решения автором своей **художественной** задачи.

Как хотелось бы, чтобы таких вопросов **на форуме было бы больше.**

Comment: Да, Ваша трактовка верна. Насчёт причастия "сжавшиеся", ещё в первом ответе Вы пояснили мне, что слово "уплотненный" прочитывается как обобщение, поэтому в него можно вложить любую конкретику, нужную мне. 

Не без удовольствия признаю, что Ваш вариант нравится мне несравнимо больше, и, конечно он несравнимо удачнее. Он лучше подходит по смыслу, к тому же остаётся некоторое пространство для моей, а также читательской интерпретации, но ровно в той степени, чтобы не запутаться, и таким образом все из нас остаются в выигрыше

Comment: Согласен, что тире в конце предложения лишнее - здесь я немного заигрался. Единственный вопрос, который у меня остался касается наречия "почти": стоит ли его добавлять? 
 
"В руке — лишь горстка (почти) предельно уплотнённых минут, прежде чем полночь обрушится легковесным плоским касанием, — и потеряю голову"

И не могу не спросить, смотря с каким вниманием , щепетильностью и совестливостью Вы отвечали: могу ли я через несколько месяцев вновь написать Вам? Что бы вы не только посмотрели, что у меня получилось, но и разделили со мной радость результата?

Comment: Обещаю в свою очередь не надоедать вам. Что ж как бы там не было: Спасибо, Вам, за неравнодушие, любовь к нюансированности и слову. Виртуально жму, со всем уважением Вашу руку (к сожалению, не знаю кем вы работаете: корректором или редактором). Так же желаю всяческих успехов и удачи. Надеюсь, что ещё напишу Вам, поскольку Ваше мнение мне неподдельно интересно. В наше время редко встретишь настоящего профессионала, которому не всё равно

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение, и, конечно, вы можете мне написать. Не знаю, буду ли я постоянно работать на форуме, но заглядывать буду в любом случае, поэтому увижу ваше сообщение.  Желаю вам удачи. // Подумала  я над вашим вариантом: горстка уже таких почти уплотнённых минут.  У меня было «предельно уплотненных», по аналогии с «предельно сжатыми». Сначала  казалось, что ваш вариант  не очень подходит, а потом включила воображение. Вот время сжимается, а что это значит?  Было исходное количество минут, вот уменьшилось на минуту, на две…А потом превратилось  в несколько минут, и их все меньше.

Comment: Предельное сжатие/уплотнение – это одна минута, дальше пойдут секунды. Если все это хорошо представлять, то думаю, что можно так сказать)

Comment: Изначально так представлялось и мне)